# Adding data to files

Tags: java

```
private void AddAccount(String usernamenew, String passwordnew) {
    final String FileName = "F:/TextFiles/loginaccs.txt";
    File file = new File(FileName);
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            bw.write(usernamenew);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write(passwordnew);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

In this method, I tried to write two **extra lines** to a text file, which is a new username and a new password.

After deleting some of the lines, the program deletes everything in the text file and write two lines, which is not what I wanted.

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: try `BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file),true);`

Answer (score 2):

After you write to the `BufferedWriter`, for the file, you then close it, which is fine.

However, you then create another `FileOutputStream`. In addition, you should not have a reader and writer of the same file at the same time. All you need to do is create the BufferedWriter, write the file and close it.

```
private void AddAccount(String usernamenew, String passwordnew) {
    final String FileName = "F:/TextFiles/loginaccs.txt";
    File file = new File(FileName);

        try {
           // BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            bw.write(usernamenew);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write(passwordnew);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.close();

           // FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);      
           // fos.close();

           // br.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: But there is another problem: It deletes everything in the file and write two lines. Is there anyway to keep the original text and add the new one?

Comment: Well, that's kind of a different question and has been answered very clearly here (and is very easy to do): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java